# Link error when adding unit tests to legacy solution

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, googletest, boost-test

I'm currently evaluating unit testing frameworks for our dev team and hit a problem I can't figure out how to solve.

Our application is build using Visual Studio 2017. The solution contains 17 projects. Most of them developed by another team (basically 3rd party library from our viewpoint) and most projects produce a dll file. One project is configured to build the executable.

It's that exe project that I can't seem to test. I've tried both Boost::Test and Google.Test. When i try to write tests using a class defined in one of the dll projects, it works as expected.

But when I try to test code from the exe project, I get LNK2019 "Unresolved external symbol" linker errors for the code defined in the exe project. The include directories are set correctly, the test project references the relevant other projects. I'm at a loss.

After some online search and tinkering with newly set up test solutions I identified two possible causes:

- Can't test code in a projct producing an exe file
- Can't test code in projects compiled with __stdcall

Could my linker error be caused by this? And if so how do I resolve the error?

Comment: Usually a test framework utility (an executable) will load your code, execute the tests, and report the results. An executable can't load another executable and run its code - the code under test has to be in a dll for that to work.

Comment: Yes but when the test executable is built, shouldn't it be possible to link in the code under test from the object files?

Comment: @PixelSupreme yes, it is possible - but it is very hack-y. You would need to explicitely link to each and every object file or you would get linker errrors (as you do right now). You served much better by adapting a proper long-term solution, e.g. turning the .exe project into a library, unti-testing that library as normal, and creating a new executable project that acts as a thin wrapper and essentially invokes your old "main" in the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot (directly) unit test a project that produces an executable file. The unit test framework needs to create an executable to run (and evaluate) the unit tests, so you would end up with two main()s in the project...

I can only suggest the following: Convert the executable project into a library project (no matter if it is a .dll or static library) and move the (hopefully) tiny bit of code that is in the main() to another project which will link the (now library) project into an executable. If your main() has a lot of code, you may consider turning it into a static function, and then invoke that static function (and thus launch your application) from the "new" main() in the "new" executable project.

Then you can test your project like any other "library" project, and have no relevant code to test in your bare-bones executable project.